# HashMap problems, printing neighbors

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on a HashMap. My code will compile, but when I run it, I don't get what I should be expecting. I my code for `printAllNeighbors` and `getNeighbor` are not working. Can anyone help me. I think I understand what I am doing, that is why I am confused.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class House
{ 
    private int streetNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String owners;
    HashMap <String, House> myNeighbors; 

    public House (int streetNumber, String streetName, String lastName)
    {
        streetNumber = streetNumber;
        streetName = streetName;
        lastName = owners;
        myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); 
    }
    public int getStreetNumber()
    {
        return streetNumber;
    }
    public String getStreetName()
    {
        return streetName;
    } 
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return owners;
    }
    public void setStreetNumber(int streetNumber)
    {
        streetNumber =this.streetNumber;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName)
    {
        streetName = this.streetName;
    } 
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        owners = lastName;
    }
    public void addNeighbor (String direction, House h) 
    {
        myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> ();
    }
    public House getNeighbor (String direction) 
    {
        if(direction.equals(direction)){
            return getNeighbor(direction);
        }
        else{            
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void printAllNeighbors()
    {
        for (String key : myNeighbors.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println( "\nkey: " + key + " value: " + myNeighbors.get(key));
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {   
        return "Address: " + streetNumber + " " + streetName + "\nOwner: " + owners;  
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        House whiteHouse = new House (1600, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Obama");
        House jerrysHouse = new House (1602, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Mabrito");
        House guentersHouse = new House (1604, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Tusch");
        House anasHouse = new House (1609, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Posada");

        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("east", jerrysHouse);
        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("south", guentersHouse);
        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("north west", anasHouse);

        System.out.println(whiteHouse);       
        whiteHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + jerrysHouse);
        jerrysHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + guentersHouse);
        guentersHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + anasHouse);
        anasHouse.printAllNeighbors();
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you are getting, and what you are expecting.

Comment: I am getting Null 0, Owners 0, I am expecting to get the neighbors of the whitehouse, jerrysHouse, guentersHouse, ect.

Comment: Hi @Deborah_Watson if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `addNeighbor` method, you are creating a new HashMap object each time it is called instead of adding elements to the map.

Try using the HashMap put method. Something like:

```
myNeighbors.put(direction,h);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ?

```
 public void addNeighbor (String direction, House h) 
    {
        //myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); This is not correct
         myNeighbors.put(direction,h); // use this 
    }
```

And initialise you map at the begining like below,

```
Map <String, House> myNeighbors= new HashMap<String, House>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following problems with your code. First inside the constructor
if you want to refer to objects field you should be using this reference, otherwise it would update the local variables only.

```
public House (int streetNumber, String streetName, String lastName)
{
 this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
 this.streetName = streetName;
 this.owners = lastName // Note this you were previously assigning value of owner to lastName
 myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); 
}
```

and use

```
myNeighbors.put(direction,h);
```

instead of

```
myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your constructor and setter methods. You are making assignments that have no effect. For example

```
public House (int streetNumber, String streetName, String lastName)
{
    streetNumber = streetNumber;
    streetName = streetName;
    lastName = owners;
    myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); 
}
```

From the constructor above, you have not initialized the fields properly. 
'streetNumber' and 'streetNames' are parameters in your constructor so the will over shadow (hide) private data fields 'streetNumber' and 'streetName', to access this private data fields you should use the 'this' key word for. Also instead of 
    lastName = owners; 
in your constructor, it is supposed to be 
    owners = lastName;
So this is the modified constructor

```
public House (int streetNumber, String streetName, String lastName)
{
    this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    this.streetName = streetName;
    owners = lastName;
    myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); 
}
```

Your setter methods have this same problem, so for setStreetNumber() method,
change

```
streetNumber = streetNumber; to 
this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
```

and do the same for setStreetName() method

Answer (score 0):

I have do some changes in your code to make it running reply if something is not according to your expectation

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class House
{ 
    private int streetNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String owners;
    HashMap <String, House> myNeighbors; 

    public House (int streetNumber, String streetName, String lastName)
    {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.owners = lastName;
        this.myNeighbors = new HashMap <String, House> (); 
    }
    public int getStreetNumber()
    {
        return streetNumber;
    }
    public String getStreetName()
    {
        return streetName;
    } 
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return owners;
    }
    public void setStreetNumber(int streetNumber)
    {
        streetNumber =this.streetNumber;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName)
    {
        streetName = this.streetName;
    } 
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        owners = lastName;
    }
    public void addNeighbor (String direction, House h) 
    {
        myNeighbors.put(direction,h);
    }
    public House getNeighbor (String direction) 
    {
       return myNeighbors.get(direction);
    }
    public void printAllNeighbors()
    {
        for (String key : myNeighbors.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println( "\nkey: " + key + " value: " +   myNeighbors.get(key));
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {   
        return "Address: " + streetNumber + " " + streetName + "\nOwner: " + owners;  
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        House whiteHouse = new House (1600, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Obama");
        House jerrysHouse = new House (1602, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Mabrito");
        House guentersHouse = new House (1604, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Tusch");
        House anasHouse = new House (1609, "Pennsylvania Ave", "Posada");

        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("east", jerrysHouse);
        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("south", guentersHouse);
        whiteHouse.addNeighbor("north west", anasHouse);

        System.out.println(whiteHouse);       
        whiteHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + jerrysHouse);
        jerrysHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + guentersHouse);
        guentersHouse.printAllNeighbors();

        System.out.println("****************************** \n" + anasHouse);
        anasHouse.printAllNeighbors();
    }  
}
```